# JSON/Javascript Object Literal Syntax

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the following and which is the preferred?

**Option 1**

```
var object = {
    'propertyName':'propertyValue'
}
```

**Option 2**

```
var object = {
    "propertyName":"propertyValue"
}
```

**Option 3**

```
var object = {
    propertyName:'propertyValue'
}
```

I realize option 2 is true JSON syntax.

Comment: Hm, whichever the coding style of your team prefers. The third one lets you use a limited set of characters for the key, because it needs to qualify as an identifier. Otherwise, you decide.

Comment: This is hard to answer. One is JSON, which is JavaScript independent. The other is JavaScript object literal syntax as you put it. What is preferred is opinion based. If you are in JavaScript, writing JSON is unnecessary unless you are transmitting it to another source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all equivalent in Javascript.

Javascript makes no distinction between using single and double quotes when writing a string.

When specifying the keys of an object literal, you need to quote it if it's not a valid identifier, or if it's a reserved keyword. Otherwise, you can write it as a string, using either quotes.

Preference is a personal style question. Most programs are written using the last syntax, but you can occasionally run into problems. For instance, Internet Explorer rejects `class: "value"` as a syntax error because `class` is a reserved word, so it needs to be quoted. I frequently encounter this problem when using jQuery to create elements, e.g.

```
$("<div>" {
    id: "foo",
    class: "fooClass"
});
```

will cause an error in IE.

Answer (score 2):

None of these are JSON. They are all varying versions of JavaScript code which uses JavaScript's literal syntax for object creation.  All accomplish the same (depending on the chars or keywords you're using in the property name) and it is up to you which you choose (though you should be consistent).

JSON is a platform independent serialization scheme for transporting data between platforms/environments/processes. Its syntax consists of a subset of JavaScript's literal syntax. JSON is always a string.

In the former, it's your choice. In JSON, the spec is very clear that the style used in your second example would be used when writing JSON (though, again, your second example is not actually JSON). JSON serializing any of those variables would produce the following in a string:

```
{"propertyName": "propertyValue"}
```

This is true on any platform which supports JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If the JavaScript code is being run in a browser, there is no difference.

The "preferred" syntax is largely an opinion, but I see property names without quotes more often than not.

Using quotes does allow you to use non alpha numeric characters in property names when defining an object in JSON:

```
var config = {
    "foo.url": "/foo",
    "foo.timeout": 3000,
    "foo^10": 100
};

config["foo.url"];
```

I've used this before in a config object where I don't want deeply nested properties, but I do want a sudo namespacing scheme to the property names.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between any of these syntaxes. You are free to use any of these if you are using this in javascript.

JSON is a bit different it's cross platform object literal. Programmers mistakenly don't create errorfull code, that's why it's syntax make it strictly use " quotes for keys.

So without quotes

```
{ "i-name" : "Some value" }
```

will be totally wrong, as it has hyphen in it.